# Unsual behaviour while multiplying an integer value with value fetched from a xml document in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, multiplication

I am using this script to find out daily visitor and total pageview for the day.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
- <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">

- <aws:UrlInfoResult>
- <aws:Alexa>
- <aws:TrafficData>

- <aws:UsageStatistic>
- <aws:TimeRange>
  <aws:Months>1</aws:Months> 
  </aws:TimeRange>
- <aws:Rank>
  <aws:Value>2426210</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>-12536204</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:Rank>
- <aws:Reach>
- <aws:Rank>
  <aws:Value>2757065</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>-12015838</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:Rank>
- <aws:PerMillion>
  <aws:Value>0.4</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>+1200%</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:PerMillion>
  </aws:Reach>
- <aws:PageViews>
- <aws:PerMillion>
  <aws:Value>0.21</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>+4000%</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:PerMillion>
- <aws:Rank>
  <aws:Value>2206561</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>-12826154</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:Rank>
- <aws:PerUser>
  <aws:Value>3</aws:Value> 
  <aws:Delta>+200%</aws:Delta> 
  </aws:PerUser>
  </aws:PageViews>
  </aws:UsageStatistic>
  </aws:UsageStatistics>
  <aws:ContributingSubdomains /> 
  </aws:TrafficData>
  </aws:Alexa>
  </aws:UrlInfoResult>
- <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode> 
  </aws:ResponseStatus>
  </aws:Response>
  </aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

This file is saved somewhere in the server.

Using this code for fetching

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("PATH To FILE", null, null, 'aws', true);
$pageview=$income_data->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->TrafficData->UsageStatistics->UsageStatistic->PageViews->PerMillion->Value;

$daily_pageview=$pageview*10;
```

Everything is fine until i found that the results were not right for few domain values. Then i tried to echo each of the value and i found out that it is ignoring values after point(.)

```
[Like for example]
.02=>0
.100=>0
1.02=>1
```

In above case value of `$pageview=0.21` and output is `0` but it is supposed to come `2.1`.

Any help with this would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's the way the value is being casted from a SimpleXMLElement, at least that's what the below points to.

```
<?php
$xml = '
<testdata>
    <foo>1.2</foo>
</testdata>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo get_class($xml->foo);  //SimpleXMLElement

echo 1.2 * 2;               // 2.4
echo $xml->foo * 2;         // 2
echo (float)$xml->foo * 2;  // 2.4
```

Comment: got it thanks ..as well i have find out a function in php termed as floatval() which do the same .. thanks